# react ethersjs metamask with Custom RPC provider

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, react

in my react app i want to use alchemy/someother-provider RPC
and i want to  use metamask as singer ( window.ethereum )

how to i set that  ?

my current code :

> var provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider (RPCURL); var
> contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, NEWABI, provider);
> var contractsinger = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, NEWABI,
> provider);

after conecting to metamask the "contractsinger" becomes  :

```
  var providerforsinger = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any"); 
   signer = providerforsinger.getSigner();
   contractsinger = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, NEWABI, signer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this

```
const getProviderOrSigner = async (needSigner = false) => {
    
    const web3Provider = new providers.Web3Provider(provider);

    if (needSigner) {
      const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
      return signer;
    }
    return web3Provider;
  };
```

Here `needSigner` will be true or false based on data

Moreover to call the function from smart contract

```
const signer = await getProviderOrSigner(true);
const Contract = new Contract(
        TOKEN_ADDRESS,
        abi,
        signer
      );
      
      const tx = await Contract.functionName();
```

Comment: but where i add the window.ethereum so it will use metamask as singer ?

Comment: there is no need for that the above code uses metamask! just try it

Comment: this code uses either singer or provider ... i want to use both ... for example if user read data there will be return depending on msg.sender...